# aws lambda returning 403 for http/1.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS Lambda behind AWS API Gateway and when I hit it with a HTTP/1.1 request I get a 403, but when I hit it with a HTTP/2 request I get the expected response.
Possibly the 403 is a red herring (might be another response being masked) but how can I get the right response with a HTTP/1.1 request? I don't see any obvious place where the minimum HTTP version can be set.

Comment: check more detail log of API gateway in cloudwatch. you can set log setting in`'API Gateway - YOURAPI - Stage - Logs/Tracing - CloudWatch setting`.

Comment: @GNOKOHEAT where is Logs/Tracing? I'm at the Stages menu item and picked the state, then I get a list of endpoints.

Comment: 1. Sign in to the API Gateway console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway. 2. Choose an existing API 3. Choose a stage 4. You can see `Logs/Tracing` menu in the Stage Editor.